# Necessary steps to validate a (PDF/PKI) signature

Tags: java, pdf, signature, pki

I have several PDFs that contain at least one PKI signature.
What steps are essential to fully validate that the signature given is valid for this PDF?

I currently gathered the following steps:

```
//TODO Build and verify certificate chain (trust)  
//TODO Check revocation list (...)  
//TODO Check self-signage  
//TODO Define trust anchors (set root CAs)
```

I need to solve this in Java.
Language inspecific help would be highly appreciated as well.

Comment: "essential to fully validate". There is more... you need 1. find out what bytes are signed. 2. hash those and compare to the hash 3. check the PDF permissions (if any), 4. check the changes that have occurred to the PDF since the signing, to see if they are allowed or not (based on what changed, and it was permitted or not.

Comment: You also have to know which validation model to follow. E.g. the model currently used by Adobe Reader does not require proofs of existence (digital time stamps) for most entities while the ETSI validation model requires a lot more.

Comment: You may be interested in [eSignature DSS](https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/wiki/display/CEFDIGITAL/DSS) which in particular implements fairly complete creation and validation of PAdES signatures. The main missing parts are items 3 and 4 on @Ryan's list.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. Currently it is assumed, that the algorithm in use will only be PCKS#7 detached. I will have a look at eSignature DSS which on the first look seems like a decent tool

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with [iText](https://itextpdf.com/en)  libraries. They have the most comprehensive and well documented libraries in java for pdf and digital signatures.

Comment: The encryption itself is still based on Bouncy Castle. For a detailed description how to do it in iText, i found this very resourceful PDF: https://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/2018-12/digitalsignatures20130304.pdf